# Java Variables Conventions

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm confused with variable declarations in Java code.

I read... don't try to use global variables declarations .

Don't use something like this:

```
package cls;
public class test { 
   private String var;

   public someMethod(){ ... } 
}
```

And use ?

```
package cls;
public class test { 

   public someMethod(){ 
       String var = null;
   } 
}
```

I don't know which is the correct way....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It totally depends on what you need.

Your first example, however, isn't a global variable--it's an instance variable.

Variables should have as small a scope as possible. This makes code easier to reason about.

Instance variables are central to what OOP is all about--classes (objects) exist to encapsulate object state, and the methods that operate on that state. For example, a `Person` class would likely have first and last name instance variables:

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    // Plus getters and setters for each.
}
```

This allows instance methods to access the first and last name variables directly without having to pass them between all the methods that need them.

The second example is a local variable. It's visible only in the method it's declared in. A reference to it may be passed to other methods.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. Neither of those are global variables. The first one is a class field. It's unique to each instance of the class that you make. Class fields (ie. variable) stay with the instance of the class until the class itself is deleted.

The second one is a method scope variable. It's only there for temporary purposes to perform the calculations needed for the method to work, and once the code in the method is done, the variable goes away.

You use each for different purposes. For example, if you're writing a Car class, you'd probably have a class field for SteeringWheel and Brake. But if you had a method to calculate the average miles per gallon, you might create a method scoped variable to help perform the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't have global variables. The first variable is class level and maintains the state of class instances and hence exists as long as an instance of the class while the second is a method's local variable that exists only during method's execution. You can use the first variable to store state information that spans multiple method calls. The second variable disappears as soon as the control leaves the method. Also, every time you call the method another variable, accessible by the same local name is created on the stack.

Comment: As noted below, Java does have global variables in the form of public static class members.

Comment: @ScottA There are differences between global variables in languages that define such variables and public statics in Java. These variables are not global in scope. In fact they have class scope and require qualification to be accessed. Also, public statics exist from when the class is loaded until it's unloaded. See section 4.12.3 of Java Language Specification (3rd edition) for all kinds of variables in Java.

Comment: @AdamZalcman There is no *practical* difference between a C/C++ global in a #include and a public static (not final) class variable. It can be accessed and modified from anywhere in the program, the same coupling issues still exist, there is no access control, and it's difficult to know all of the places the public static is being used. The only advantages Java public statics have are consistent initialization and namespacing. In general use, however, public statics are just as corrosive to maintenance, testing, and code safety as a global in any other language.

Comment: @ScottA You're right, even though Java doesn't have actual global variables, it provides you with something equally evil: public statics. I also agree that the differences between globals in C/C++ and public statics in Java are minuscule, especially from practical perspective.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have truly "global" variables in Java the same way as you can in a language such as C. Java forces you to structure your program in an object oriented way.

In your example above, if `var` is required throughout a whole `test` object and is important to have stored, then you would use the first example. If `var` is only required in `someMethod` and it's not important for a `test` object to store it then use the second example.

Take note that even with the first example, `var` is *encapsulated* within a `test` object, so it's not really "global" at all, apart from maybe slightly to the member function of `test` (which is the whole point of instance/member variables).

The closest thing in Java to "global" data is something like:

```
public class GlobalVars {
   public static int globalInt;
}
```

And you could access `globalInt` throughout your code as `GlobalVars.globalInt`, without creating an instance of `GlobalVars`.

Comment: Actually, practically speaking a static class member is global in the same way that it would be in C. There is a single instance of the variable available to the entire process, and it can be modified by anything anywhere. Using a static class member in this fashion (public, not final) is just as dangerous as a global in C. PL/SQL has the same functionality with its package specification variables, which are namespaced the same way Java public statics are, but still globally accessible.